# How can i create my Onepage smoothscrool WordPress theme?

Tags: theme-development

I just want to know that i have an one page theme with smooth menu effect in my theme.In my theme i have home,about me,my skills,services,portfolio and contact me.How can i create my one page WordPress theme with the loop or i have to add different page for each sections.Its really confusing will you please help me out?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405017/how-create-responsive-one-page-wordpress-theme-with-scrollable-effects/19405402

Comment: Its very helpful the link u gave me but now i want to know that, i have a about me sections so what should i do? 'post_type' => 'about', <- is it like that with loop? Or i have to create a page name About me. So i have services,portfolio so every time should i do the same?
Hope you give me this answer too.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want to do. If you have an about page then you can have child pages and each child page would be a section